# zend framework 1 Form - Note element lost its value if there is validation error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a Note element in my zend framework 1 form used for registration. It is defined in the format:

```
$captcha_reload =   new Zend_Form_Element_Note('captcha_reload',  
                                array('value'=>"<div id='captcha_reload_div'>
                                                <a href='javascript:return false;' 
                            id='change-image'>Change text.</a></div>"));        
$this->addElement($captcha_reload);
```

This element displays a hyperlink and displays perfectly during registration page call.

The problem is during form submission. This note element doesn't displays anything (ie missing the hyperlink) if there is form validation error.

I have checked and tried the code below:

```
$this->setDefaults(array('captcha_reload'=>"<div id='captcha_reload_div'>
                                                <a href='javascript:return false;' 
                            id='change-image'>Change text.</a></div>"));
```

But still there is no value if there is form validation error.

For Note element, I have included the following in the Zend Registration Form page:

```
class Zend_Form_Element_Note extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml  
{  
   public $helper = 'formNote';  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Zend_Form_Element_Note extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml  
{  
   public $helper = 'formNote';  
   public function isValid($value, $context = null)
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

I have added that isValid() into Note class and it works fine. It doesn't need to use _setValue() inside Note class.

Answer (score 2):

When the form is submitted it is over-riding the `value` property of your element. As there is nothing being submitted, when the form is `echo`ed again to show form errors, the value of the element is nothing as well.

Perhaps adding an `isValid` function to the element?

```
// pseudo-code
public function isValid($value, $context = null) {
  $this->_setValue("<div id='captcha_reload_div'><a href='javascript:return false;' id='change-image'>Change text.</a></div>");
  return true;
}
```

This will reset the value to your custom text, and return true without doing any checks (as you know the value is what you want it to be). Subsequently, when the form `echo`s again it will show the value as set in `isValid`

Comment: Is it possible to do this from Zend Form ? Because, passing the HTML from Controller is not good and also need to change both places to make changes. setDefault doesn't work for me. You know something like that which helps to set a default value.

Comment: Add that function into `Zend_Form_Element_Note`. Alternatively, in the form create an `isValid` function (get the signature from Zend_Form) and do something like `$this->getElement('captcha_reload')->setValue("<div ... etc"); return parent::isValid($data);` This will do the same job but will be located in the form object instead of the note element object.

Comment: It works. Actually, I didn't understand that your code is added into Note class. I have edited your code and accepted the answer. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have edited your answer but I couldn't see the changes now. Can you make two changes to your answer, so I can accept it. Change 1: Remove the line starts with "$this->_setValue(..."  Change 2: Copy your code starts with "public function isValid...." into my Note Class above ie "class Zend_Form_Element_Note.."  Then your answer will be clear for others.